# table mapping in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a Model1.edmx, which has several tables. Now, I do not want all the columns of the table TableA, so I created another entity and mapped it with TableA using table mapping.

I am facing lot of issues while doing the same. The error that I get is,

```
" Thier primary key may collide".
```

If I create the FK association, it says `"Non-Primary-Key column(s) [XXX] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties".`

I am not sure, if the approach that I am taking is correct, as entity set alraedy exists for TableA.

If this is the approach what would be the solution.

If not, which way should I go.

**UPDATE** : I did delete the properties that were not required, also, I added the properties from other tables that were FK in the TableA.

Now I am getting error `" Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 566:Must specify mapping for all key properties (TableAs.ID) of the EntitySet TableAs.`"

**UPDATE** I added the other tables properties as they were FK, and I wanted few columns from the other table in the UI. Is this a good (or possible) approach? or should I create classes for it, and then map each property of the class manually?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by this:

> Now, I do not want all the columns of the table TableA, so I created another entity and mapped it with TableA using table mapping.

Is not entirely clear. Do you mean that you only want to deal with a subset of the columns in `TableA` and ignore the others everywhere in the application? Assuming they're nullable (or have a `StoreGeneratedProperty` of `Computed`), you can just click on them in the entity for `TableA` and delete them.

You can't create another entity that's mapped to `TableA` unless you're dealing with table-per-hierarchy inheritance, which it doesn't sound like you're interested in.

Comment: I do not want columns that are internal for database or development purpose. I only want to expose columns that would be of use for the UI (or the user). Also, I am not sure about "table-per-hierarchy feature", can you elaborate on that.. or may be just googling on that will help?

Comment: @Priya: What you're talking about doesn't have anything to do with table inheritance, so only look it up if you're interested in learning what it is; it won't help you with this problem. Like I said above, if the columns are nullable, then you can simply remove the column properties from the designer. If they aren't nullable, then you can't remove them because the entity couldn't be saved.

Comment: Ok, so should I remove it from the entity or entity set? And it wont affect any crud operations?? Also, is there any way to rename the columns in the entity?

Comment: Also, how do I handle FK in the entity, should I create POCO for it, I mean I want to know the best way of doing it!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; the only place you can remove a property is from an entity, since entity sets don't have properties. As for CRUD operations, if you remove the fields, then update and insert statements will not include these columns. If you have further questions, please either update your question or post a new one.

Comment: Updated the question, Excuse me for my silly questions as I am new to EF.